# How to override dependencies within Scopes in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

How can you override dependencies within different scopes of Dagger 2? Example:

I have two components in my app: `ApplicationComponent` and `ActivityComponent`. `ApplicationComponent` is the base component and `ActivityComponent` is a scoped component where I want to perform the override.

For this example I created those models:

```
public class Parrot {

    private final HelloPrinter helloPrinter;

    public Parrot(HelloPrinter helloPrinter) {
        this.helloPrinter = helloPrinter;
    }

    public void sayHello(){
        helloPrinter.print();
    }
}


public interface HelloPrinter {
    void print();
}


public class AppHelloPrinter implements HelloPrinter{

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Application");
    }
}

public class ActivityHelloPrinter implements HelloPrinter {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Activity");
    }
}
```

And the code:

```
ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().build();
applicationComponent.provideParrot().sayHello();
activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                        .applicationComponent(applicationComponent).build();
activityComponent.provideParrot().sayHello();
```

My desired output is:

```
Hello Application
Hello Activity
```

So I made the modules:

**ApplicationModule:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    Parrot provideParrot();
}

@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HelloPrinter providePrinter(){
        return new AppHelloPrinter();
    }

    @Provides
    Parrot provideParrot(HelloPrinter helloPrinter) {
        return new Parrot(helloPrinter);
    }

}
```

**ActivityModule:** Attempting to override the HelloPrinter

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    Parrot provideParrot();

}

@Module
@PerActivity
public class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    HelloPrinter provideHelloPrinter() {
        return new ActivityHelloPrinter();
    }     
}
```

But with this config the output is:

```
Hello Application
Hello Application
```

What do I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I think it is not possible to override module in Dagger2. If it suits you, you can try to mark them as @Named("Activity") and @Named("Application")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is...you can't do that.

With dagger everything is done at compile time.

1. You have an application component, that knows how to construct a `HelloPrinter` and a `Parrot`.
   You then expose the `Parrot` for all Components to use.
2. You have your activity component, that also knows how to construct a `HelloPrinter`!

**So what happens?**

Keep in mind the object graph. Components know what they can build and depend on other components, exposing known objects themselves.

```
applicationComponent.provideParrot().sayHello();
```

This one is easy. You create the component, you want a parrot and it is constructed using the known Printer.

```
activityComponent.provideParrot().sayHello();
```

What happens here, is (basically) the same. You say you want a parrot. Your activity component does not know how to make one, it just knows how to make a printer!
*But wait.* It has a dependency on an application component, conveniently exposing a `Parrot` Factory.

The application components factory gets called and the parrot gets instantiated. Since the application module *knows* how to build a printer, it uses the one at hand.

**...now what**

So...you could provide Parrots in your activity component, they then would use a different printer!

> Gradle: error: Parrot is bound multiple times

Here we would get 2 Parrots into our object graph, since there is no "overwriting" happening. This won't work, and shouldn't.

**Conclusion**

There is no way to *override* methods. As soon as you declare a second `Parrot` or `HelloPrinter` it will fail compilation.

The only possiblity to achieve a similar functionality would be to use `@Named()` annotations on which printer to use and / or pull the whole parrot creation down into the activity module.

And please correct me if I am missing something, but I don't even see a way to keep the signature the same with using named annotations.